# get actual file name of selected item c#

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

What I am looking for is to get the actual file name of an the image.
I have 2 images as following in the xaml.

```
<Image Grid.Column="0" 
       Source="Assets/1.png"
       MouseLeftButtonDown="selected"/>
<Image Grid.Column="1" 
       Source="Assets/2.png"
       MouseLeftButtonDown="selected"/>
```

When user clicks on any image I neeed to get which image is clicked. Ie, the file name.
1.png or 2.png . I get only the path and not file name in sender function.

```
private void selected(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Image pic = (Image) sender;
}
```

Comment: What exact string do you get from the sender? Like "D:\MYAPP\Assets\2.png" or "D:\MYAPP\Assets" or "2.png" or what? And what do you mean by "actual file name"?

Comment: i need 2.png or 1.png

Comment: But what do you get from sender's Source Property?

Answer (score 1):

pic.Source.Split('/') Returns an array :) 
Use [1] in this case or LastOrDefault if you like Lamdba